# For loop in jinja using exported variable

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to generate some code in a for loop and the limit is set dynamically from an exported variable. This is what I was trying

In test.mk

```
export num_iterations = 3
```

In test.j2

```
{%- for i in range(0, {{ num_iterations | int }}) %}
        Do something with  {{i}}
{%- endfor %}

Error I get
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

If I use range(0, 3), the code generation works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inner {{ }} so your for looks like this:

```
{%- for i in range(0, num_iterations | int ) %}
```